# How can I sketch in the Messages app

Tags: messages, ios

Before iOS 8 was released, I remember watching an Apple demo where they sketched on a picture inside of the Message app before sending the message. Does anyone know how to do this? Was this functionality pulled from the release of iOS 8?

Comment: It was probably sketching on the mail app.

Answer (score 1):

This is not your just your memory. In response to your question that feature requires the jail broken platform "*Cydia*". The specific feature is called *Graffiti* and you need 2 or more languages enabled on your device's keyboard for it to work, once you have that hold the globe icon on you're keyboard for it to work.
For more info I found this site and I think it explains best here's the link Hope it helps :)

http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-compose-texts-or-imessages-on-iphone-with-drawings-handwriting-and-sketches/